# I create a One to One realtionship in django Multitable-Inheritance but it not show Book-id in my child class Table and also show Integrity Error Why?

Tags: python, django, django-models

This is my models.py :

```
class Book(models.Model):
    Book_Name = models.CharField(max_length=100, default="Don Quixote")
    Author_Name = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, default="Miguel de Cervantes")
    Price = models.FloatField(default=175.00)

    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    update = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.Book_Name

class ISBN(models.Model):
    book = models.OneToOneField(Book, on_delete=models.CASCADE, parent_link=True, primary_key=True)
    Isbn = models.CharField(max_length=100)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.Book_Name
```

in according to my code every Book has one isbn number but in admin panel ISBN table don't show book attributes or don't show any book-id. it show only Isbn column and after i give input in this column it show me error "IntegrityError at /admin/inheritance/isbn/add/" and "NOT NULL constraint failed: inheritance_isbn.book_id"

This is my admin.py :

```
@admin.register(Book)
class PostAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ['Book_Name', 'Author_Name', 'Price']

@admin.register(ISBN)
class PostAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ['book', 'Isbn']
```

I'm a noob to python and Django so any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: For multi-table inheritance, `ISBN` is supposed to inherit from the concrete model `Book`so `class ISBN(Book):`

Comment: My question is why it not show OneToOne relation? and why it not show book id in ISBN table?

Comment: Ah right, could be something about `parent_link=True`. Try to remove it

Answer (score 0):

Try changing `book` on `PostAdmin.list_display` for `book__id`

```
@admin.register(ISBN)
class PostAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ['book__id', 'Isbn']
```